# Is banking safer with tails and its unsafe browser, than with a debian live CD?

Tags: tails

The Tails live CD is meant for anonymity but might its security features make it a safer way to do your online banking, shopping and bitcoin shopping using its "unsafe browser", compared to a regular debian live CD? Tails is supposed to be fully open source for starters, but can someone confirm this? Might a libre derivative of debian be safer for the stated purposes? Might a Kali live CD be safer? What about the TENS live CD for the US military?

Answer (score 1):

> The Tails live CD is meant for anonymity but might its security
>   features make it a safer way to do your online banking, shopping and
>   bitcoin shopping using its "unsafe browser", compared to a regular
>   debian live CD?

The "unsafe browser" is just Firefox without a proxy.

> Tails is supposed to be fully open source for starters, but can
>   someone confirm this?

Here's how you get the [source code](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/git/) to see for yourself.

> Might a libre derivative of debian be safer for the stated purposes?

It's still the same Firefox code (a.k.a. Iceweasel)

> Might a Kali live CD be safer? What about the TENS live CD for the US
>   military?

No idea. You're asking questions here that need to be posed to those specific projects.

If you're not using hidden services (aka `.onion` sites) then you should be using [https](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS). If you don't need the anonymity that Tor provides then https is usually good enough. Further question about infosec should go to the [infosec stackexchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/) unless you have questions specifically about Tor.

Comment: Thanks. And the Tor Browser is just firefox with a few addons installed? Ie its sources have not been modified or any modifications are just user interface niceties and no security enhancements?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately some banks, like UniCredit, at least in Italy, don't know at EU level, blocks access via Tor.

They don't forbidden officially the use of anonymity proxy systems, but they block all exit nodes.

The strange is that they let you login, but at first webpage after you logged, you are kicked out the site and connection is reset with a generic error message.

And if you do it 3 times you must activate restore procedure

Comment: interesting... and completely unnecessary (resp. another point why UniCredit is unsympathetic)! because as soon as you are logged in, you identified yourself.